# I am trying to group rows based on sum of Qty column not exceeding the value 10

Tags: t-sql

TSQL: Best way to group rows so that sum of the quantity won't exceed a value say 10

```
ID  | Qty | Grp
---------------
ID1 | 5   | 
ID2 | 2   | 
ID3 | 5   | 
ID4 | 4   | 
ID5 | 4   | 
ID6 | 3   |
```

Expected Result

```
ID  | Qty | Grp
---------------
ID1 | 5   | 1
ID2 | 2   | 2
ID3 | 5   | 1
ID4 | 4   | 2
ID5 | 4   | 2
ID6 | 3   | 3
```

Comment: Would u please explain more that how `Grp` column is deduced?

Comment: That's lovely. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on writing a _question_. And _best_ requires a specific metric.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question, no evidence of research or work, ... .

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. The syntax might need some minor adjustments. Alternatively you could probably use a CTE if performance is an issue.

```
DECLARE gMax int;
SET gMax = 1;

DECLARE gTotal int;
SET gTotal = 0;

WHILE gMax < 100
BEGIN
    WHILE gTotal < 10
    BEGIN
        UPDATE (select * from dbo.MyTable where [Qty] is not null)
            SET [Grp] = gMax
            SET gTotal = gTotal + [Qty]
        END
        SET gMax = gMax + 1
END
```

Comment: Not that you've provided code that could run, but it appears the intent is to assign the same group number to _every_ row on _every_ iteration through the loop, as long as the row has a `Qty` value. The group sum is not limited to `10`, it merely changes the group number if it matches _or exceeds_ `10`. OTOH, since `gTotal` is not reset on each iteration it shouldn't need to iterate more than once.